# python compare CSV and find difference

Tags: python, csv, comparison

I've two CSVs as :

CSV1

```
id, count
1, 5
2, 10
100, 1
```

CSV2

```
id, count
100, 5
1, 10
2, 1
```

I need to compare the CSVs with **id** and get the count for both and find the difference. My expected result would be:

```
id, Diff
1, -5
100, -4
2, 9
```

For now i'm using nested loops as :

```
with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as t1, open('csv2.csv', 'r') as t2:
fileone = csv.DictReader(t1)
filetwo = csv.DictReader(t2)
csv1 = list(fileone)
csv2 = list(filetwo)
for data in csv1:
    for datum in csv2:
        if data['id'] == datum['id']:
            diff = int(data['count']) - int(datum['count'])

            if diff > 0:
                print(diff)
                item = [[
                    str(data['id']),
                   str(data['count']),
                  str(datum['count']),
                  str(diff)]]
                writer.writerows(item)
```

But since the above code does a loop inside a loop, it takes forever if i have large files O(n^2). Is there anyway i can easily do a comparison in python.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `pandas` IMHO

Comment: have you looked into `pandas`? a simple `join` with some arithmetic would make this blazing fast

Comment: without pandas, you could use a dictionary to match the ids. That would reduce complexity to O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `O(n**2)` code:

```
fileone = csv.DictReader(t1)
filetwo = csv.DictReader(t2)
csv1 = list(fileone)
csv2 = list(filetwo)
for data in csv1:
    for datum in csv2:
        if data['id'] == datum['id']:
           diff = int(data['count']) - int(datum['count'])
           ...
```

can be replaced by creating 2 dictionaries using the id field as keys, then perform the intersection of the keys. Then loop on the intersected keys:

```
csv1 = {data["id"]:data for data in fileone}
csv2 = {data["id"]:data for data in filetwo}
keys = set(csv1) & csv2
for k in keys:
    data = csv1[k]
    datum = csv2[k]
    diff = int(data['count']) - int(datum['count'])
    ...
```

now you have approx `O(n)` complexity (dict lookup is `O(1)` in average)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv', index_col='id')
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv', index_col='id')
df_diff = df1-df2
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df_diff)
```

Output:

```
      count
id         
1         5
2        10
100       1
      count
id         
100       5
1        10
2         1
      count
id         
1        -5
2         9
100      -4
```

Pandas will handle the index alignment (`id` in your case) for you, and will use compiled `numpy` arithmetic for *much* faster computation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv',names=['id','count_1'])
df2=pd.read_csv('csv2.csv',names=['id','count_2'])

df_merged=df1.merge(df2,on='id')
df_merged['diff'] = df1.count_1 - df2.count_2
```